# Spring MVC Endpoint not fetch while pass empty map {} into GET Request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, endpoint

Facing the issue into the endpoint fetching

Below is the case while I call the api get the response.

`http://localhost:28080/restServices/apps/1762/users/USERNAME/?password=PASSWORD`

But when ever I set following data it's not working could any body help me out into this issues.

`http://localhost:28080/restServices/apps/1762/users/USERNAME/?password=PASSWORD&data={}`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/apps/{appId_}/users/{username_}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public UserResponseDTO getUserAndToken(@PathVariable Long appId_, @PathVariable String username_, @RequestParam("password") String password_, @RequestParam("data") String datas) throws Exception {
//do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

This problem with any edit it's works into the Tomcat Version `7.0.63` While another version `7.0.73, 8.0.x +` not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of behaviour  affect of major update of `Tomcat`.

For a quick fix, you can downgrade to one of older versions, I downgraded tomcat with `7.0.63` .

After getting more R&D on `Spring MVC` It's reject the request while adding list of invalid character into request listed below.

Excluded US-ASCII Characters disallowed within the URI syntax:

```
   control     = <US-ASCII coded characters 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal>
   space       = <US-ASCII coded character 20 hexadecimal>
   delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">
```

List of unwise characters are allowed but may cause problems:

```
unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
```

The following characters are reserved within a query component and have special meaning within a URI/URL:

```
  reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

[For more information visit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Solution:

```
encodeURI("http://localhost:28080/restServices/apps/1762/users/USERNAME/?password=PASSWORD&data={}")
> http://localhost:28080/restServices/apps/1762/users/USERNAME/?password=PASSWORD&data=%7B%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify {appId_} in `value = "/apps/users/{username_}"`

Fix: `value = "/apps/{appId_}/users/{username_}"`

~~~

Your method accepts `@RequestParam("data") String datas`
and you're sending `data={}`
String should be quoted so the fix is `data=""`

Comment: already into code I added but here by mistake to removed.But still not works

Comment: Try with fixing 'data' string.

Comment: So I need to set something like wise` , @RequestParam("data") String data)`.
@sovas I set according you said but still not working.

Comment: it's working into string but want to pass empty map into GET request.Can you please try to look into my request.

Comment: So you want to have String data or Map<K,V> data?

Comment: I changed as you said but still not getting the resolution @RequestParam("data") Map<String,String>  data_)